# Data are not saved into database eventhough the code works correctly

Tags: php, html, database

Im trying to register a user into a database.The code works correctly but data arent saved into database in the end.The final output is "You are registered successfully!wIT for admin confirmation" as it should be.This is my registration form:

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
print ("<form action='register.php' method='post'>
    <p>Name
        <input type='text' name='firstname'  />
    </p>
    <p>Surname
        <input type='text' name='lastname' />
    </p>
    <p>Username
        <input type='text' name='username' />
    </p>
    <p>Password
        <input type='password' name='password' />
        </p>
        <p>Email <input type='text' name='email'/>  </p>
      Enter your CV: <p> <textarea name='cv' cols='60' rows='50'></textarea> </p>

      
    
  <input type='submit'  value='Register'/>  
</form>

        ");



if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['firstname'] )&&isset($_POST['lastname'])&&isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])
  &&isset($_POST['cv'])/*&&isset($_POST['notat'])&&isset($_POST['lendet'])*/&&isset($_POST['email'])){
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$email=$_POST['email'];

$cv=$_POST['cv'];
/*
$notat=$_POST['notat'];
$lendet=$_POST['lendet'];
*/

$query = "INSERT INTO  login (firstname, lastname, username,password,cv,email,admin,approval) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
 '$username','$password','$cv','$email',0,0)";
}
if ( !empty($firstname)&&!empty($lastname)&&!empty($username) &&!empty($password)&&!empty($cv)&&!empty($email))
{
  if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
}
echo "YOU HAVE BEEN REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY!PLEASE WAIT FOR THE ADMIN APPROVAL!";

}
else echo "Fill in all the blank fields";
mysql_close($database);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my database:[image: The database]

Comment: Chk databse connected or not

Comment: Plz write this line seperatly if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )

Comment: U r using || operator for them its not good.. mysql_* is deprecated... codw open for sql injection... not using error_reporting... double checks..

Comment: Suppose if databse connect than condition is true... in this how u use $database in dbconnect connection???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin usually needs refreshed to see the updated data.
Hit reload or click elsewhere and back to display new data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, aside from using mysql_connect and not mysqli or prepared statements, the easiest way to debug such issue is to just echo out the query and try to run it in either phpMyAdmin or your favorite mysql client.